# Unable to connect mbed lpc1768 with putty , com ports not showing

Tags: windows, arm, cortex-m, mbed, lpc

**my Code :**

```
#include "mbed.h"

DigitalOut myLed(LED1);

int main() {

  while(1) {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    myLed=1;
    wait(1);
    myLed=0;
    wait(1);
  }
}
```

The LED is blinking just fine , and I'm trying to connect my device to putty, and when I click on serial, it asks for serial line and I read it should be a COM port, but when I go to device manager there are no COM ports showing. I did a little research and found that I might have to add it manually so I did but this is what I get and I still can't connect putty to my mbed device.[image: my device manager]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [Mbed Serial Driver](https://os.mbed.com/handbook/Windows-serial-configuration).